# how to implement custom method when Polly circuit is close

Tags: c#, fallback, polly, circuit-breaker, policywrap

I have method which returns `IAsyncPolicy<HttpResponseMessage>` and it has 2 or more policies along with `CircuitBreaker` and part of my DI.

Now in my implementation class I added one extra fallbackPolicy to handle `BrokenCircuitException` and wrap it with `IAsyncPolicy<HttpResponseMessage>` (AsyncPolicy)

Now I did my custom method implementation within `DoWork()` method, Great!!! Thanks to `FallbackAsync` policy where I'm catching `BrokenCircuitException` exception, means when circuit is open.

```
var fallbackPolicy = Policy<HttpResponseMessage>
                .Handle<BrokenCircuitException>()
                .FallbackAsync(async (cancellationToken) => await DoWork()
                .ConfigureAwait(false));

            var policyWrap = fallbackPolicy.WrapAsync(AsyncPolicy);

            // Send message to service
            var response = await policyWrap.ExecuteAsync(() => HttpClient.PostAsync(...
```

Now question is, do we have any policy or a way to know when the circuit is close and I can write my own method implementation?

In my shared policy where I have CircuitBreaker` too which I wrote as in DI area have below signature, but I can't write my custom method implementation here.

```
onReset: () =>
                    {
                        Trace.TraceInformation("Web API Close");
                    },
```

Comment: Please provide more information on what is preventing you writing your custom method implementation in the `onReset` delegate hook.

Comment: My method is in different class, how to hook that method here?

Comment: Can it be made a static method? Or does the method need to be executed on an instance of that other class? Is the method to be executed during `onReset` the same for all uses of the circuit-breaker policy instance? Or is it intended to differ at different call sites consuming the circuit-breaker policy instance? What is the overall goal?