# how to capture CircuitState for AsyncCircuitBreakerPolicy

Tags: c#, polly, circuit-breaker, retry-logic, policywrap

I have a variable `asyncPolicy` of type `IAsyncPolicy` which has one or more policy including `AsyncCircuitBreakerPolicy`. Now I want to get specific policy say `AsyncCircuitBreakerPolicy` before a API call, so that I can extract the status of Circuit.

Is this possible? then how? Below code gives error, 'IAsyncPolicy' does not contain a definition for 'GetPolicy'

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var asyncPolicy = CreateDefaultRetryPolicy();

        var breaker = asyncPolicy.GetPolicy<AsyncCircuitBreakerPolicy>();
        var state = breaker.CircuitState;

        //Web API call follows with asyncPolicy

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    public static IAsyncPolicy CreateDefaultRetryPolicy()
    {
        var retryPolicy = Policy.Handle<BrokenCircuitException>().WaitAndRetryAsync
            (
                retryCount: 3,
                sleepDurationProvider: attempt => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Math.Pow(2, attempt))
            );

        var circuitBreaker = Policy.Handle<HttpRequestException>().CircuitBreakerAsync(
        exceptionsAllowedBeforeBreaking: 3,
        durationOfBreak: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5000),
        onBreak: (exception, timespan, context) => { },
        onReset: (context) => { });

        return Policy.WrapAsync(retryPolicy, circuitBreaker);
    }
```

Comment: This should be tagged as C++ instead of C

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.GetPolicy<T>()` is [only for PolicyWraps](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/wiki/PolicyWrap#methods). Technically, it is an extension method on `IPolicyWrap`.

You could change the return type of `CreateDefaultRetryPolicy()` to be `AsyncPolicyWrap`

```
public static AsyncPolicyWrap CreateDefaultRetryPolicy()
```

Or you could cast where you call `.GetPolicy<T>()`

```
var breaker = ((IPolicyWrap)asyncPolicy).GetPolicy<AsyncCircuitBreakerPolicy>();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. You keep helping me since few days. Would you mind my this question, if you have any thoughts? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58928939/how-to-implement-custom-method-when-polly-circuit-is-close